# How can I visualize 6 dimensions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

*"Before starting to implement any learning algorithm, it is always good to visualize the data if possible".*

This quote is from Andrew Ng "Machine learning".

I want to use a Logistic Regression to predict missing values for Age (Titanic). My goal is not to have the best result but do it for fun.

But I don't know how I can how I can visualize 6 dimensions:
1. Pclass
2. Sex
3. Age
4. SibSp
5. Parch
6. Fare Embarked

Andrew Ng told about some examples with 2 dimensions. It's easy to visualize the data. But how I can visualize the data (to find missing values for Age) if I have 6 dimensions?

Maybe I can use principal component analysis (PCA) to perform dimensionality reduction but I hope that I can find more easy method than PCA (Andrew Ng told that PCA is good for dimensionality reduction)

Comment: you don't always visualize all dimensions at the same time ;)

Comment: This maybe off topic here, but usually when visually a high dimension mathematical object, it's easier to look at the contours. This has special meaning in statistics - a contour plot will visualize the dependency of two variables. Make a few of these. (Think of a topographic map visualizing a 3d terrain).

Comment: You can try parallel coordinates.  This should work ok for 6 dimensions, provided you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates

Comment: malioboro, you are right. I sow how other people solved this task (Titanic on Kaggle). Some of them did not use 6 dimensions. They used 2 dimension (for example, 'Embarked' (x) and 'Survived' (y), etc.). I tried parallel coordinates for 'age' but I did not see anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is pretend that the structure is a list of lists, because that's really what it is. So, in Python, if you have several lists to work with, you put those lists in a list of its own, like this L = [[a,b,c], [a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]]. Now what if each one of a,b,c, a1, etc. is a list too? I won't write it out to avoid confusing you, but you can easily imagine that that would be so simple to implement - just by adding another layer of square brackets for the third dimension members. You can go as deep as you like in this fashion.